# Fetching UDP stream in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-container

I have a docker container running ffmpeg. My host machine is a windows. I am creating a udp stream using VLC from my host machine. I want to transcode that udp stream in my docker container. Is it possible? Currently I cannot fetch udp stream on my container although ffmpeg is running fine. I am a novice in docker.

Created udp stream in vlc and tried to access it inside container.
docker run -it -p 3002:5000 -d image-name (5000 is my node port)

Comment: You want to send strem from Docker container to host?

Comment: Exactly the reverse of what you said @RichardRublev